# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'express' imported from F:\Document\My Project\NODE JS\Sample 1\tinder-backend\server.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, nodemon

**This is the error. How I fix this....**

node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'express' imported from F:\Document\My Project\NODE JS\Sample 1\tinder-backend\server.js
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:884:9)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:929:18)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1044:11)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:222:40)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a module 'express'.
You have to install it with:

```
npm i -s express
```

this will install express and save it in package.json

Comment: but error not correct yet.

Comment: what does it show ?

Answer (score 0):

When working with ECMAScript modules in Node.js, you are required to provide the file extension, as mentioned in the official documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions.

In addition to the "type": "module" setting in package.json, you also need to explicitly specify the file extension when importing modules, like this: `import {urls} from './helpers.js'`.

To maintain the previous behavior of resolving JavaScript files as modules using the `require` syntax, you can use the `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` flag.

To sum up, when using ECMAScript modules in Node.js, remember to provide the file extension while importing modules, and you have the option to utilize the `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` flag to maintain compatibility with the `require` syntax.